# Why does the sum function not work with pyarrow fields?

Tags: python, pyarrow

Consider the following list of fields.

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
fields = [ds.field('a'), ds.field('b'), ds.field('c')]
```

`sum(fields)` produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument 'self' has incorrect type (expected pyarrow._compute.Expression, got int)
```

However, interestingly, `functools.reduce` gets the job done.

```
>>> import functools
>>> import operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.add, fields)
<pyarrow.compute.Expression add_checked(add_checked(a, b), c)>
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't give `sum()` an initial value, it defaults to `0`. But pyarrow doesn't allow you to add an integer to a field, so you get a type error.

`functools.reduce()` uses the first element of the list as the initial value.

You can get the equivalent with `sum()` using:

```
sum(fields[1:], start=fields[0])
```

Comment: Cool. Alternatively, `sum(fields, start=ds.scalar(0))` seems to work too, assuming the fields are numeric.